# Play 2.0-RC3 -- Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am trying to use Play 2.0 RC3. I have extracted the framework into my Program Files folder, and renamed the folder 'play20'. I entered that folder into my Windows path.

When ever I run Play, whether it being `play help` or `play new`, I always get `Error: Could not find or load main class Files\play20\repository`

I tried going into the folder itself instead of running from the path and I still get the same response.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Copy the folder to a path without spaces in the name. "Program Files" has a space in the name and this often causes problems.

As a suggestion, copy the Play folder to the root of a hard drive (C:, D:)

Comment: This seems to work. I just find it interesting how this is not a bug in Play 1.4.x

Comment: @KayleL  remove `${JAVA_OPTS}` could work

Answer (score 2):

Running Play 2.0 in Windows

I had Problems running Play 2.0 after download.
I installed it in c:\Program files\develop\play which caused problems with the blank in the path.

I patched the play-2.0\play.bat and play-2.0\framework\build.bat according to the space-paths.patch in [this playframework google group entry](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/zp3JoILlBBg/7_KdxmDMajQJ)

In play-2.0\play.bat replace the code

```
setlocal

set p=%~dp0
set p=%p:\=/%
set buildScript=%~dp0framework\build.bat
set additionalArgs=%*

if exist "conf\application.conf" goto existingApplication

:noApplication
java -Dsbt.ivy.home=%~dp0repository -Dplay.home=%~dp0framework -Dsbt.boot.properties="file:///%p%framework/sbt/play.boot.properties" -jar %~dp0framework\sbt\sbt-launch.jar %*
```

by

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set p=%~dp0
set p=%p:\=/%

set fp=file:///!p: =%%20!
set buildScript="%~dp0framework\build.bat"
set additionalArgs=%*

if exist "conf\application.conf" goto existingApplication

:noApplication
java -Dsbt.ivy.home="%~dp0repository" -Dplay.home="%~dp0framework" -Dsbt.boot.properties="%fp%framework/sbt/play.boot.properties" -jar "%~dp0framework\sbt\sbt-launch.jar" %*
```

and in play-2.0\framework\build.bat replace the code

```
set PLAY_VERSION="2.0"

if defined JPDA_PORT set DEBUG_PARAM="-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=%JPDA_PORT%"

set p=%~dp0
set p=%p:\=/%

java -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M %DEBUG_PARAM% -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Dplay.version="%PLAY_VERSION%" -Dsbt.ivy.home="%~dp0..\repository" -Dplay.home="%~dp0." -Dsbt.boot.properties="file:///%p%sbt/sbt.boot.properties" -jar "%~dp0sbt\sbt-launch.jar" %*
```

by

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set PLAY_VERSION="2.0"

if defined JPDA_PORT set DEBUG_PARAM="-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=%JPDA_PORT%"

set p=%~dp0
set p=%p:\=/%
set fp=file:///!p: =%%20!


java -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M %DEBUG_PARAM% %JAVA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dplay.version="%PLAY_VERSION%" -Dsbt.ivy.home="%~dp0..\repository" -Dplay.home="%~dp0." -Dsbt.boot.properties="%fp%sbt/sbt.boot.properties" -jar "%~dp0sbt\sbt-launch.jar" %*

:end
endlocal
```

This did the trick for me for a **new** project.