# Does anyone know how to run the scala executable in Git Bash shell?

Tags: scala, git-bash

I have installed Scala on my Windows 7 system. When I run "scala -version" from the Windows command prompt, I get:
    Scala code runner version 2.11.4 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
When I run "scala -version" from a Git Bash shell, required by Swagger and other frameworks, I get:
    Error: Could not find or load main class Files

Does anyone know how to run the scala executable from a Git Bash shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that you've installed Scala on `C:\Program Files (x86)` or `C:\Program Files`.  As far as I can tell, git bash has problems reading the classpath if it has spaces and/or "()" in it.

If you're on a Win7 64-bit system, the easiest thing for you is:

1. Edit the system variables PATH
2. Find the scala\bin entry
3. Replace the `C:\Program Files` with `Progra~1` or `C:\Program Files (x86)` with `Progra~2`

If you're not on a 64-bit system, (which I can't verify due to not having one), you'll have to do some escaping so that `PATH` isn't screwed up with the spaces and/or ().

EDIT: Here's a related SO but with Play instead: [Play 2.0-RC3 -- Error: Could not find or load main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529433/play-2-0-rc3-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class)

Answer (score 1):

Install scala with **Coursier** and run the **scala.bat** command from git bash terminal

Comment: Can you [edit] in some examples?